# Use Sum() function with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What is the correct syntax for using `Sum()` function in python for lists?
Say we have a list called `list_1`. When I tried these two syntax I get the same result:

```
total_1 = Sum(list_1)
total_2 = list_1.Sum()
```

What is the best syntax for that?

Comment: [`sum` has a little s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).  The "same result" you're getting is probably an error telling you that Python doesn't recognize the name you gave.  `sum(list_1)` is correct.

Comment: `list` doesn't have a `Sum`/`sum` method, so you should have received an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Can you post a working example? - it should only require one extra line setting `total_1` to a list. If this snippet works for you, it suggests that you are importing some other thing that as a `Sum` function and a collection with a `Sum` method.

Answer (score 1):

To sum a list of integers or floats, the correct method is:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
total = sum(list_1)
print(total)
```

which results in the output:
`6`